# Angular 2+ How can I trigger a toggle directive by a mouseleave event in a sibling component

Tags: angular, angular-directive

When the user's mouse enters the yellow square (found in the yellow component) the appToggle directive is triggered (making isActive = true) changing the squares background to grey, **this works**.

However I would like to be able to trigger the directive via the sibling component (the blue square found in the blue component) making (isActive = false) when the user's mouseleave's the blue square.

Please see [stackblitz code example showing the problem](https://stackblitz.com/github/nicohaitas/angular-directive).

**toggle.directive.ts**

```
  @HostListener('mouseleave', ['$event'])
  onMouseLeave(event) {
    if (event.target.classList.contains('blue')) {
      this.isActive = false;
    }
  }
```

The problem is that...

```
event.target.classList.contains('blue')
```

is being completely ignored, I get no errors, but nothing is actually happening.

I have searched everywhere to find a similar example which might solve this problem but have not been able to.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, many thanks in advance folks!

Comment: Do you mean the yellow turn gray when mouse is hover on blue square?

Comment: @Maihan Nijat no, I mean grey turn yellow when the mouse leaves the blue square.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a working solution, [mouseout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseout_event) which makes use of mouse event bubbling. Code changed to the following...

```
@HostListener('document:mouseout', ['$event'])
  onMouseOut(event) {
    if (event.target.classList.contains('blue')) {
      this.isActive = false;
    }
  }
```

For the sake of brevity and should anyone else be interested I also updated [stackblitz with the working solution](https://stackblitz.com/github/nicohaitas/Angular-Directive-Working/?file=src%2Fapp%2Ftoggle.directive.ts)

Answer (score 0):

The directive you applied knows nothing about the blue square.

From the docs:

```
The @HostListener decorator lets you subscribe to events of the DOM element that hosts an attribute directive
```

https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives#directives-overview

So `event.target` in your case holds a reference to the yellow square

You can achieve the desired effect via multiple paths, but most reasonable is probably to create two directives:

`appToggle` - should toggle its state on mouse enter

`appToggleSwitch` - should accept a reference(https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#ref-vars) to the component it needs to change on some event:

`appToggleSwitch` directive:

```
  @Input('appToggleSwitch') componentToToggle: any;

  @HostListener('mouseleave', ['$event'])
  onMouseLeave(event) {
    this.componentToToggle.classList.add('grey');
  }
```

App component:

```
<div class="yellow" appToggle #yellow></div>
<div class="blue" [appToggleSwitch]=yellow></div>
```

Comment: this a great solution however in my case the two squares are sibling components and not two div in the same component. I will test this solution in sibling components and let you know if it worked.

Comment: just tested your code with sibling component and it generates the following error... ERROR TypeError: "this.componentToToggle is undefined". This makes sense as template reference (#yellow) is not in the same component. However thank you so much for attempting a fix.

Comment: @Nikolaos you could try to add the reference to top level app component 
```
<app-yellow appToggle #yellow></app-yellow>
<app-blue [appToggleSwitch]=yellow></app-blue>

```

But maybe some adjustments to the components themselves will be needed

Comment: I will run this test tomorrow morning and get back to you

Comment: your suggested implementation did not work as appToggle and appToggleSwitch both need to be added directly in the element in the template for angular to bind to that element. If I am not doing something correctly, please fork the stackblitz code example above and provide me a working version, with your suggestion. Thank you again.